# How to make a background box around a fraction ("bbox") with Katex?

Tags: katex

The `bbox` command is not supported in Katex, see https://katex.org/docs/support_table.html

`bbox` with MathJax renders `\bbox[#e1ffc1,5px]{ \frac{1}{2} }` like:

[image: bbox with mathjax]

I have tried in Katex the alternative command:

```
\colorbox{#e1ffc1}{ \frac{1}{2} }
```

but it throws the error:

> KaTeX parse error: Can't use function '\frac' in text mode at position 21: …rbox{#e1ffc1}{ \̲f̲r̲a̲c̲{1}{2} }

Likewise `\fcolorbox` does not work.

How to get the background box in Katex around a fraction to work?

Answer (score 1):

> In LaTeX, `\colorbox` puts its contents into text mode. And KaTeX is a bit pickier about text mode than MathJax is.

> You can still put math inside the box, but you have to explicitly shift it from text mode back into math mode with $…$ delimiters. So, to get your example working, try `\colorbox{#e1ffc1}{$ \frac{1}{2} $}`

Credits @ronkok via https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/discussions/2531

Alternatively you could add colorboxes only around the elements within the formulas.

Or you dismiss the idea of having a background color, and instead you set the color of the formulas themselves, using e. g. `\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}` or `\textcolor{red}{\frac{1}{2}}` (seems also to accept formulas!).